# Is there a common linux utility/way to query information about all the disks on a system?

Tags: linux, hardware, disk, hard-drive

I'm writing a script that will gain remote access to machines in a lab and assess the disks in the system and what it is used for.  I need to:

```
 1. get all of the disks in a system, this also includes SAN disks as
       well as non standard HW raid controllers.
 2. check if the disks are part of a software raid.
 3. check the disk for partitions and if they are boot-able.
 4. gather basic information about the drive including manufacturer block size etc. .
```

The problem that I am running into is that there doesn't seem a very convenient place to find all of this information with out writing 10+ pages of regular expressions of each of the utilities that need to be used to find this information.  Surprisingly, this is easier on windows since I can use WMI.  IS there a much more programmatic way to gather all of the information that I seek in linux?

Comment: kpartx, partprobe, blkid, lshw; cfdisk and parted

Answer (score 3):

The tools I'd think of:

- `kpartx`, `partprobe`, `blkid`, `lshw`; `cfdisk` and `parted`

I think `parted` is geared to automation.

`lshw` has xml output.

Comment: I would love to use lshw.. However, it isn't uniform across all Linux distributions. Also, the other operations you have listed work mostly with changing partitions on drives and not readily for reading meta data about the drive. I'm thinking more along the lines of iterating through /sys/class/block to gather information about each block device.

Comment: Mmm? partprobe, blkid, kpartx do **not** deal with modification at all. sfdisk and parted can be used to query information. In fact parted is bound to give the most information (since it needs the info to support its features anyway)

Answer (score 0):

`mount`

`mount [-l] [-t type]`
lists all mounted filesystems (of type type). The option -l adds the labels in this listing.

http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount

Comment: This will only list file systems.. I need the whole organized disk structure of the entire system.